# Can't figure out why Slect2 is not working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-select2

I have an application (MVC5/C#), where the users have requested a searchable textbox within the dropdown.  Exactly like Select2.  And Select2 seemed pretty simple and straightforward.  But, I cannot get it working.  At first, I thought maybe it was something within my application - so I decided to isolate Select2 and create a brand new app to simply test Select2.  And it's still not working.

I have followed along an example right on their site, as follows:

In my header section I need to include my js, select2js, and select2css files (I placed these in my layout file, as Views don't have a header.  I also tried referencing these files right within the view -both ways did not work).

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/select2.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Content/css/select2.min.css")
```

Here is my View/Html (pretty basic)

```
<select class="js-example-basic-single" name="state">
<option value="AL">Alabama</option>
<option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

And my Doc Ready (bottom of View)

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {

//alert("Here");

$('.js-example-basic-single').select2();

alert("Here Again")

});

</script>
```

Here is what is happening in the above scenario:  The page loads.  I get the first Alert (So, I know we got this far).  The second alert never happens. And the dropdown is still just a basic dropdown with no search box.   I assume that means it's not able to locate the select2 js script?   But why?  The path is correct.  Am I missing something here?

I have tried calling the scripts in the header of Layout file, as well as directly at the bottom of the view. I have also tried using Select2 with the element id rather than the class, as I have seen examples both ways.

Any suggestions?

Additional Information:

Firefox and Edge Browsers do not produce any erors
IE kicks out the following error after the first alert

Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'select2'

Additional Information (2):

Below is my bundleConfig

```
    public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on bundling, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at https://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: how about the ``bundleConfig`` in ``App_Start``?

Comment: @Sajid - To be honest, I don't know much about the bundleConfig.  Self teaching myself MVC5 at the moment and that's beyond my skillset.  I did post my bundleConfig.  What would I do here?  Do I add the files to existing bundles?  Create new bundles?  Can someone provide a quick example?

Comment: You have 2 optins : 1 - add new line to BundlConfig like : `bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/select2").Include("~/Scripts/select2.min.js"))` and in the view use `@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/select2")`. 2 - add it to another bundle like : `bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js","~/Scripts/select2.min.js"));` in the view just `@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js")` sufficient

Comment: Not sure but it might be that you are rendering your css in the scripts section. In a previous project I think I used a Styles.Render("~/Content/css/select2.min.css")